# NativeScript Command failed

Tags: ios, nativescript

Command failed: ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj';
sourceConfig = Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/ns-js/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig')
targetConfig = Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/ns-js/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig')
if(sourceConfig.attributes.key?('IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET') && targetConfig.attributes.key?('IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'))
sourceConfig.attributes.delete('IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET')
end
sourceConfig.merge(targetConfig).save_as(Pathname.new('/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/WORK/ns-js/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig'))"
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from -e:1:in `'

**I installed all ns dependencies for Mac. Installed ns-ts and ns-vue and got the same error. Help me with this issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested with Ruby 2.6 but we are seeing success with `ruby 2.7.2p137`

Comment: updating ruby to version 3.0 fixed this bug

Comment: @MaksymGloba interesting, what version of NativeScript are you using?